# How to output an attribute from a populated field?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm trying to output an attribute from a populated field into the console, however I am getting undefined.

```
app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
  activeUser = await Active.findOne({}).populate({path: "_id" , model:"User"})
  console.log(activeUser.id)
```

This code outputs to the console..

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("64dad146736253c98a57e021"),
  name: 'John',
  email: '1234',
  phone: 1234567890,
  pass: '1234',
  __v: 0
}
```

This code outputs undefined.

```
app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
  activeUser = await Active.findOne({}).populate({path: "_id" , model:"User"})
  console.log(activeUser.id.name)
```

How do I output, name to the console?